# Select a varying name id of an element for a custom style?

Tags: css, css-selectors

There's a website that puts ads in iframes with ids that change on reload. They also have anti addblock:

[image]
I want to make a custom style using an extension that hides all the elements that have an id beginning with that "adsIframe". Is there any way to select all those elements?

Comment: Use the attribute selector `iframe[id*="adsIframe"]` - the asterisk global selector (`*`) indicates any `iframe` element with an `id` attribute containing the specified text (`adsIframe`)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Better to use `^`, since it will only target elements which *begin with* `adsIframe`.

Comment: @BenM Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the wildcard attribute selectors in CSS. For example:

```
iframe[id^="adsIframe"] {
   color: red;
}
```

Will select any `iframe` element whose `id` attribute **begins with** `adsIframe`. Using `*=` will target those whose `id` attribute **contains** `adsIframe`.

From [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> `[attr^=value]`
>  Represents an element with an attribute name of *attr*
>   whose value is prefixed (preceded) by *value*.